# What typescript type to use for an array body with fetch?

Tags: typescript, fetch

I am using fetch to post some url encoded form data like so:

```
private buy = async () => {
    const { nonce } = await this.state.instance.requestPaymentMethod();

    const formBody = [];
    formBody.push(`${encodeURIComponent("paymentMethodNonce")}=${encodeURIComponent(nonce)}`);

    // @ts-ignore
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/checkout`, {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: formBody,
    });
}
```

It works fine with the ignore, but what type should I use in this case so I can remove the ignore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fetch` API is part of the `DOM` API, and it is defined as part of  [`lib.dom.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts).
According to this definition, the `body` type is defined as:

```
type BodyInit = Blob | BufferSource | FormData | URLSearchParams | ReadableStream | string;
```

So, for request with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you can use `URLSearchParams` as `body` type:

```
private buy = async () => {
  const { nonce } = await this.state.instance.requestPaymentMethod();

  const formBody = new URLSearchParams();
  formBody.append('paymentMethodNonce', nonce);

  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/checkout`, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
    },
    body: formBody,
  });
}
```